# Printer disregards one-sided printing settings

Tags: 20.04, printing, brother

I use ubuntu 20.04 and Brother printer. I was able to print duplex, but now every print I do is duplex, even if I set it manually to one-sided. Restarting system or printer doesn't solve it.

It doesn't depends on application used, LibreOffice Write, Document Viewer and others print duplex, even when I set it to one-sided in the application.

It is pretty annoying, because only workaround I have is just printing every page as a sole printing job.

[image: Printer settings]

Comment: No, LibreOffice Write, Document Viewer and others all print duplex, even when I set it to one-sided in the application.

Comment: If your issue is anything like mine, you may find that it is ignoring other settings from the print dialog as well. In my case, for example, it is also ignoring the number of copies. Haven't yet found out the root cause.